# Apache Redirection

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2

I would have thought I'd find a TON of stuff out there about how to do this, but everything I try puts me into a redirection loop that causes the browser to eventually give up. I need to temporarily redirect all traffic to a site to the homepage of that site. Essentially:

```
RedirectMatch 302 /.* http://mysite.com
```

Let's chalk it up to the national holiday or working on a Sunday morning, but I can't find right solution to capture all traffic to any location within the site and redirect it to the homepage. I know I'm missing something obvious, but it's lingering in my blind spot...

Thanks.

Final solution:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^/index\.php.+$ / [QSA,L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^/(.+)$ http://mysite.com [L,R=302]
```

This is a fancier form for similar rule. Also, + stands for "one or more" while your * stands for "zero or more".

Comment: This doesn't quite get there. I don't get infinitely redirected, but a non-existent URL throws a 404 rather than redirecting.

Comment: Ugh, it's early. I had neglected to take into account that the site is running on a framework that redirects to `/index.php?url=$1`. I thought I had pre-empted that redirection, but I guess not. This solution would work otherwise, of course. I ended up with the solution added to my original question.